# Django + Wordpress: Integrating user login

Tags: django, wordpress, django-users

I would like to have one users system (preferrably Django's) to rule both Django and Wordpress.

The use case is that Django is an application embedded inside a wordpress installation (via iframe or something similar). In order to use the Django, users **must** be authenticated, authentication in WordPress is not mandatory, but recommended (for posting comments and stuff like that).

In order to ease the usage of the site, I would like the same sign-up to apply for both the Django app and the WordPress installation. Sign-up might occur either via OAuth / FB authentication (lots of Django solutions for this), or via dedicated site users. While the signup process is most important, it would be nice if certain user fields would remain synced between the two worlds.

My thoughts on the matter:

- Maybe there's an out-of-the-box solution (couldn't find any)
- Create a full-fledged django app for syncing the two user models (wp_users and django's users) via one of the following options:

  - A master(django)-slave(wp) solution, where each change in Django changes info in the wp_users and other related tables and vice-versa (via Django periodically checking the DB or creating a WP plugin). Can be implemented either by putting both django and wp on the same (MySQL) db, using XML-RPC or some other anomination I didn't think of.
  - Same as above, but let WP be the master instead of Django (seems harder).
  - An external system to rule both models - maybe make OAuth / some other external authentication mandatory, and somehow sync the two models using this?

Has anyone encountered this situation before? 
Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution? I am interested in the same problem. This shows some promise: https://github.com/sunlightlabs/django-wordpress

Comment: Anything regarding this? I am facing same problem

Answer (score 1):

You should really try to work out some approach, revising your work when encountering problems afterwards.

Nevertheless imo Wordpress is kind of bordered. I wouldn't recommend making changes to both frameworks, but fixate on Django.
For example you could create a WordpressUser(User) and create a python script a crobjob, celery task or whatever you'll need to syncronize your databases. Meaning to say you should keep things strictly separated unless you have very good reasons not to (I can't think of any).